# Invoke-WebRequest is getting blocked by my firewall

Tags: powershell

When I try `Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.youtube.com/@houdini3d/featured` I get the following error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

If I disable my Firewall it goes back to working. I am under the assumption that PowerShell has permission to access the the internet, I made a rule sometime ago in my firewall for the exe at the following path:

```
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\pwsh.exe
```

Is `Invoke-WebRequest` using a separate executable to do its job? Perhaps I need to give it permission too in my firewall? Also how can I determine that PowerShell can indeed access the internet?

I searched around and I am still lost, any help would be great.

---

Edit1:

@zett42,
So with my firewall on, I tried `Test-Connection www.youtube.com` the output I got is:

```
   Destination: www.youtube.com

Ping Source           Address                   Latency BufferSize Status
                                                   (ms)        (B)
---- ------           -------                   ------- ---------- ------
   1 SomePC           -----                  6         32 Success
   2 SomePC           ------                 6         32 Success
   3 SomePC           -----                  6         32 Success
   4 SomePC           -----                  6         32 Success
```

So this means Powershell itself is not being blocked by my firewall? hmmm... Thanks for that though, that command seems to be very usefull too.

---

Edit2:

Well this is embarassing but I will share my mistake for others.

I did infact not have my current PowerShell executable in my firewall rule.

I only noticed this after I typed up this help post. I was at some point using the preview version of Powershell, the fireware rule had this path:

```
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\pwsh.exe
```

So soon as I updated that, its back to working now.

@zett42, Pardon me for this.

Comment: Does `Test-Connection www.youtube.com` work?

Comment: @zett42 , Hey I tried your suggestion, I made an edit to my original post!

Comment: This means that ICMP (ping) protocol is let through, but it could still block HTTPS protocol. Maybe you need to add a rule to allow default HTTPS port (443).

Comment: @zett42 , Hey it was a dumb mistake on my part. I disclosed it in another edit in my post. Sorry about this.

Comment: It happens.  Voting to close this as not reproducible / typo.